# What is the difference between entering parameters in these four different ways?

Tags: vba

I often see VBA parameters being added in four different ways:

- wks.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious) - parentheses containing values separated by commas
- vls.Add vl - space followed by values
- copyRange.Copy Destination:=Cells(countD, 2) - space followed by labels, the peculiar sign := and values
- wks.Cells.Find(lookFor:="*") - parentheses containing labels, the peculiar sign := and values

So there seem to be tho dimensions:

- parenthesis or not
- label:=value or value

Can I always use any method? When is either more appropriate than the other

Answer (score 6):

> parenthesis or not

**In general you use parenthesis when:**

1) *assigning result to a variable*:

**Correct:**

```
Set rng = wks.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
```

**Incorrect:**

```
Range("A1:A5").Copy (Destination:=Range("C1"))
```

2) *doing something with result*:

```
wks.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Activate
```

3) *using with `Call` keyword*:

**Correct:**

```
Call Range("A1:A5").Copy (Destination:=Range("C1"))
```

**Incorrect:**

```
Call Range("A1:A5").Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
```

---

**You don't use parenthesis when:**

1) calling any method *without assigning result to a variable* or *doing something with result* or *using `Call` keyword*:

**Correct:**

```
Range("A1:A5").Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
```

**Incorrect:**

```
Call Range("A1:A5").Copy Destination:=Range("C1")
Range("A1:A5").Copy(Destination:=Range("C1"))
```

---

> label:=value or value

This feature called *named arguments* and it's very convenient.

A function call using named arguments differs from a regular function call in that the values are passed by associating each one with a parameter name, instead of providing an ordered list of values.

*Named arguments* are especially useful when you are calling a procedure that has optional arguments. If you use *named arguments*, you don't have to include commas to denote missing positional arguments. Using named arguments makes it easier to keep track of which arguments you passed and which you omitted. See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

E.g. `Find` method has 9 parameters (1 required and 8 optional) and if you want to specify `7th` parameter, you have two options:

**Option1:**

*Set it using it's order:*

```
Set rng = wks.Cells.Find("*", , , , , , True)
```

and when you see code like in line above, it's very hard to understand meaning of `True` because you should count place of this argument and look in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for details.

**Option2:**

*Set it using named arguments:*

```
Set rng = wks.Cells.Find(What:="*", MatchCase:=True)
```

which makes your code *much more* readable.

Additionally, when using *named parameters*, you can change order of arguments:

```
Set rng = wks.Cells.Find(MatchCase:=True, What:="*")
```

Comment: most of the syntax is just a matter of preference though

Answer (score 4):

The parenthesis or not is a vb convention, if you want to get the return value from the function you must supply the parenthesis, if you are not interested in the return value you must leave them out.

The := allows you to specify the parameters in a different order to the order in which they are declared.

```
Sub Test()

    TestParams "hello", "there" ' not capturing the return value - no parenthesis

    r = TestParams("hello", "there") ' reading the return value - parenthesis needed

    TestParams w:="there", v:="hello" ' := supply the parameters in a different order

    r2 = TestParams(w:="there", v:="hello") ' := and () to supply the parameters in different order and get the return value


End Sub


Public Function TestParams(v As String, w As String)

    MsgBox v & " " & w

    TestParams = "ok" & " " & v & " " & w

End Function
```

Comment: Why is a := used instead of =?

Comment: named parameters, plus worth mentioning when a variable is passed by val and when by ref