# vba method copy of object range failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am simply trying to copy one range on a worksheet to another range on a different worksheet. From what I understand the method is Range1.Copy(DestRange)
Do I need to specify the worksheets, like this?
Worksheets("sheet1").Range1.Copy(Worksheets("Destination").DestRange)

My code throws an error:
Runtime Error 1004:
Method 'Copy' of Object 'Range' failed

My Code:

```
Sub adsadsf()

Dim currentR As Range
Dim rawIput As Worksheet
Dim excitationWs As Worksheet

Set currentR = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
currentR.Select
Set rawInput = Worksheets("rawInput")
Set excitationWs = Worksheets("Excitation Curve")

'none of these work. all throw same error
'currentR.Copy (Range("H1"))
'currentR.Copy (Range("H1"))
'currentR.Copy (excitationWs.Range("A1"))
rawInput.Copy (excitationWs.Range("A1"))

End Sub
```

Comment: `currentR.Copy Range("H1")` without brackets. Also `rawInput.Copy (excitationWs.Range("A1"))` should be `rawInput.Cells.Copy excitationWs.Range("A1")` if you want to copy all cells (unefficient - better to copy sheet). This might be interesing: [What is the difference between entering parameters in these four different ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511707/what-is-the-difference-between-entering-parameters-in-these-four-different-ways/23512287#23512287)

Comment: @simoco - How do you expect to get the big points if you answer the question in a comment?  (+1)

Comment: @simoco Thank you! This has been driving me up a wall and I didn't really understand the logic between some methods having parenthesis and then suddenly having parenthesis causes everything to go to hell.

you are awesom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (you can add the worksheet dims back in if needed)

```
Dim currentR As Range
Dim destR As Range

Set currentR = Worksheets("rawInput").Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set destR = Worksheets("Excitation Curve").Range("A1")

currentR.Cells.Copy destR
```

Comment: Yeah I assumed as much. Use parentheses only if setting a variable as part of an equation (ie `x=do.function (variable)` or `do.function variable`). Always better practice to hard code your ranges and stay away from `.Select` if its not needed as well (hence my evolution of the code)