# Error while calling sub in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Am stuck and not able to proceed with this. Please find my code below. The code is basically to verify if an element is present in a webpage through VBA. I have created the below sub.

```
Sub ele_exist(val As String, ele As String)

Select Case val:

Case "byid":
    Set verielement = doc.getElementById(ele)
    If verielement Is Nothing Then
    msgbox("something")
    Else
   msgbox("something")
    End If

Case "byclass":
    Set verielement = doc.getElementsByClassName(ele)
    If verielement Is Nothing Then
    msgbox("something")
    Else
   msgbox("something")
    End If

Case "byname":
    Set verielement = doc.getElementsByName(ele)
    If verielement Is Nothing Then
   msgbox("something")
    Else
   msgbox("something")
    End If

End Select

End Sub
```

Now when i call this sub it gives  `syntax error`

This is where i call the above sub

```
Sub start()
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .navigate "http://www.google.com"
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
           DoEvents
        Wend
        Set doc = .document
        DoEvents
    End With
    ***ele_exist ("byname","btnK")*** - THIS IS WHERE SYNTAX ERROR IS DISPLAYED AND THE CODE IS DISPLAYED IN RED

End Sub
```

I even tried converting it to a boolean FUnction rather than sub, but no luck.

Please help

Comment: change `ele_exist ("byname","btnK")` to `ele_exist "byname","btnK"` or `Call ele_exist ("byname","btnK")`. Also check this post: [What is the difference between entering parameters in these four different ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511707/what-is-the-difference-between-entering-parameters-in-these-four-different-ways/23512287#23512287)

Comment: @simoco : Wow!! Please post this as answer so that i will accept and this can help people with similar query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentione in comments, change

```
ele_exist ("byname","btnK")
```

to

```
ele_exist "byname","btnK"
```

or

```
Call ele_exist ("byname","btnK")
```

One more possible way is to use named parameters:

```
ele_exist val:="byname", ele:="btnK"
```

For additional explanation check my another post: [What is the difference between entering parameters in these four different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511707/what-is-the-difference-between-entering-parameters-in-these-four-different-ways/23512287#23512287)