# VBA ErrorHandler MsgBox Syntax

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

This is a basic question, but I haven't found any solutions after a Google search.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I can't get the MsgBox to launch properly: it's highlighted in red. I think this is a syntax issue.

```
Sub DataProcessingExperiment7
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
...
ErrorHandler
MsgBox("Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error" & Err.Number, , , asVbMsgBoxResult)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between entering parameters in these four different ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511707/what-is-the-difference-between-entering-parameters-in-these-four-different-ways)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon it should be `ErrorHandler:`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix the MsgBox syntax problem.

Answer (score 1):

You call shouldn't be in parenthesis (brackets) unless you're wanting to return a value. Remove the brackets after msgbox

```
Sub DataProcessingExperiment7
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
...

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error" & Err.Number, ,
```

Edit:

And you have too many arguments. Remove one

Comment: `, asVbMsgBoxResult` - that bit shouldn't be there.

Comment: Apologies, it's the way I copied the text into VBE. Please ignore that part!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the user a message with an ok button then use:

```
MsgBox "This is the message", vbCritical, "This is the title"
```

The only bit you need is the message bit. You can use named parameters, like this (makes it easier to know which bit is what):

```
MsgBox Prompt:="This is the message", Buttons:=vbCritical, Title:="This is the title"
```

If you want to give the user a Yes/No, Ok/Cancel choice, then you use MsgBox as a function and store or use the result.

```
If vbNo = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you want to continue?",Buttons:=vbQuestion + vbYesNo, Title:="Are you sure?") Then
```

For your code use:

```
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Prompt:="Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, Buttons:=vbCritical, Title:="Error Handler: Error" & Err.Number
```